# Nested environmental variables in github actions

Tags: github-actions

I'm using github actions and trying to create an environmental variable of a path using the $USER system environmental variable.

This is my yml file:

```
env:
  MY_PATH: "/Users/$USER/myDir/"

jobs:
  run_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: echo path
        run: echo "$MY_PATH"
```

What is printed is:

```
/Users/$USER/myDir/
```

The expected was:

```
/Users/MyUserName/myDir/
```

Is there a way to make use of the $USER, $HOME etc. in a way that the script will expand them to the text they hold?

Comment: The command `env` prints all possible environment variables. According to my quick test, there aren't such variables like `$USER` or `$HOME`.